# How to tell when an inflated view has been drawn?

Tags: android

When a user clicks a button on my main view, I inflate a new view and add it to my main view. My new view contains a TextView with the default text of "HelloWorld", while setting up the view I setText("You have just come from...") and I getLeft() and getRight() on my textview. Problem is, it's returning coordinates as if the text was still "HelloWorld".

I think it's probably doing this because the updated text hasn't been drawn yet. But if I click a button in this new view and in onClick do the getLeft() and getRight(), it works correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create a class for your view and then override [View.onFinishInflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29) and do your stuff there.

Should be a really short class, with only this method overridden.

Alternatively, you could use the solution suggested here: [ViewGroup finish inflate event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517636/viewgroup-finish-inflate-event)
But the downside is that you will get called back each time the layout is redone or updated, not only after inflate.

Answer (score -1):

here's a way to do this without extending or overriding anything:

```
private static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(final View view, final Runnable runnable)
{
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    final OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
            runnable.run();
            final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    };
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
}
```

in the runnable parameter , you can get the updated size and position and everything else that you need.

alternatively , you can use [`addOnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener%29) instead of [`addOnPreDrawListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnPreDrawListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener%29) if you wish.

EDIT: Alternative to runJustBeforeBeingDrawn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126