# RecyclerView: How to determine when scrollToPosition() has finished binding the ViewHolders

Tags: android

**tl;dr** How to wait until the true scrolling is done after calling scrollToPosition()? What I mean by true scrolling is that (1) the `RecyclerView` has finished the scrolling and (2) it has bound all the `ViewHolder`s for the set position of scroll.

**Description:**

I am trying to fix some transition animation for recycler view and I'm having a hard time achieving it.

The app is consistent of a `RecyclerView` in one of the activities and a `ViewPager` that acts as a "detail view" when users click on an item in the `RecyclerView`.

The forward navigation from `RecyclerView` to `ViewPager` works perfectly fine but the problem is, the backward navigation doesn't work. Please note that the user may navigate using the `ViewPager` in the detail view and when they re-enter the activity with `RecyclerView`, the position of the item may be different from the original case, meaning the `RecyclerView` needs to scoll first to the item and then resume the transition animation.

The reason I can't make it to work is because I resume the animation *before* the `RecyclerView` has properly scolled and bound the underlying `ViewHolder`s but I don't know how to wait for the scrolling to truly finish and then resume the shared element transitions.

What I do in my code (on the `Reenter` code) is this:

```
if (isReentering) {
        // postpone the animation here
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(getActivity());
        scollIndex = ... // determine the correct item position
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(scrollIndex);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = getRecyclerView();
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        recyclerView.requestLayout();
                        ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(getActivity());
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I also set the transition name in my `Adapter` as such:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ....
    holder.setTransitionName(_data.get(position).getContentId().toString());
}
```

The transition name is the UUID of the item, set in the underlying `View`. Both the `ViewPager` and the `RecyclerView` set this correctly.

The `scrollIndex` is correct and the `RecyclerView` does scroll to it but here's the catch: The scrolling and binding only takes effect **after** I've already started the postponed enter transition in my code (by calling `ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(getActivity());`) which causes weird transition animations.

What I would like to happen is to somehow *wait until the scrolling and the `ViewHolder` binding is finished* before calling `startPostponedEnterTransition` so my question is, how can I find out when the scrolling has finished and all the `ViewHolder`s are bound so that I can call this?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I need to make sure that a `ViewHolder` was bound and is available too for a custom animation...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user25 Unfortunately not.

Answer (score -1):

You can check, if the ViewHolders have been bound, by using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854673/2305095).