# RecyclerView item height and width change dynamically Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development and I am developing an app where the app downloads pictures from server and show them in a gridView. But some extra spaces are coming up when the app is run on a bigger screen phone. Here are some screenshots. How do I solve this ? I have the model of each item with a fixed height and width of 110dp

My image model :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/post2"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="1.5dp" />
```

My Recycler View :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/gallerygrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

[image: On smaller screen phone]

[image: On bigger screen phone]

Comment: Show your xml file

Comment: it is necessary to create a xml layout for bigger screen phone..

Comment: I just posted the codes

Comment: If your height is fixed calculate then maintain aspect ration for width too or set as a full width

Comment: @ShakilMahmudShanto please check my answer below it helps you and give proper result in all device

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Set height and width dynamically according to the screen size. this is the best way to get perfect result.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        //if you need three fix imageview in width
        int devicewidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 3;

        //if you need 4-5-6 anything fix imageview in height
        int deviceheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 4;

        holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().width = devicewidth;

        //if you need same height as width you can set devicewidth in holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height
        holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height = deviceheight;
```

try this in adapter in getview hope you get better result in all device

**EDIT:** 
Or to set same height same as width you can set devicewidth in height also like below:

```
holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height = devicewidth;
```

Comment: If you getting any problem with above code please feel free to ask :) :)

Comment: I use my recyclerView in two activity by to state (vertical and horizontal). Can i use this code in activity instead of adapter?

Comment: @ZakiPathan do you mean to put that code in onBindViewHolder instead of getview?

Comment: will not works if RecyclerView contains NOT whole screen. What if RecyclerView have only 30% of screen width and 40% of screen height (for sample)?

Answer (score 24):

for those who want to do it in the xml layout (recyclerView item) file you can use a ConstraintLayout
by combining

```
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and the following code for having a square item

```
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:4"
```

and don't forget to provide all the constraint that way you can set

```
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
```

hence the complete code will be as follow

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:4"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/event_placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine with android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get `RecyclerView` width after it's measurement. See [How to find width of item in recyclerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490737/how-to-find-width-of-item-in-recyclerview/50495163), [How to know when the RecyclerView has finished laying down the items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397460/how-to-know-when-the-recyclerview-has-finished-laying-down-the-items).

For instance,

```
recyclerView.post {
    val width = recyclerView.width
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using Constraint layout use constraint Dimens ratio as
  mentioned above.

  ```
  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>
  ```
- else if you are using linear or relative layout.

  ```
  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
  ```

both will solve your problem but both of them are only recommend if you have small amount of data to populate, these tricks are not recommended for thousands of images, as this will calculate and set height of each item at run time which means this will **run on main thread** and for thousands of images this will create a **laggy scrolling** and may result in **ANR** on low end devices.

**There is another work around to minimize this lag.**

You can get the width of the imageView at runtime in onBindViewHolder and set the height equals to width or any multiple of width to attain your desired ratio.

```
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      val width = holder.image.width

      withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
           holder.image.layoutParams.height = width
      }
  }
```

Getting the width at background thread will take the load off of Main thread which ultimately results in smooth scrolling.