# How to set different height for each items in recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to set a different height for each item in a recycler view. Normally we are getting the same height for every row. But I need different heights, for instance, if the first three rows are 70 in height then I need the remaining with height 0. My code is as follows. In this code its not set properly. Please suggest me an edit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView rvListProfiles;
private ListProfileAdapter listProfileAdapter;
private String[] list = new String[]{"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rvListProfiles = findViewById(R.id.rvListProfiles);

    listProfileAdapter = new ListProfileAdapter(list, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rvListProfiles.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    rvListProfiles.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvListProfiles.setAdapter(listProfileAdapter);
    String listString = Arrays.toString(list);
    System.out.println("List "+listString);
}
}
```

**item xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImage"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/love"
    android:transitionName="imageTransition" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:transitionName="nameTransition" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileDesc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileImage"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profileName"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@string/dummy_data"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:transitionName="descTransition" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**ViewHolder class**

```
public class ListProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public ImageView profileImage;
public TextView profileName;
public TextView profileDesc;
public RelativeLayout parentLayout;
public Context context;

public ListProfileViewHolder(View itemView, Context mContext) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = mContext;
    profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    profileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
    profileDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileDesc);
    parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
}

}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class ListProfileAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListProfileViewHolder> {

private String[] list;
private Context mContext;
private int height[] = {70,70,70,
                        0,0,0,0};

public ListProfileAdapter(String[] list, Context mContext) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ListProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View layoutView = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, 
null);
    return new ListProfileViewHolder(layoutView, mContext);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListProfileViewHolder holder, int 
position) {


    holder.parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            height[position]));
    holder.profileName.setText(list[position]);
    holder.profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent sharedIntent = new 
Intent(mContext,SharedActivity.class);
         sharedIntent.putExtra("name",holder.profileName.getText());
         sharedIntent.putExtra("desc",holder.profileDesc.getText());
         Pair[] pairs = new Pair[3];
         pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String> 
(holder.profileImage,"imageTransition");
         pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String> 
(holder.profileName,"nameTransition");
         pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String> 
(holder.profileDesc,"descTransition");

         ActivityOptions options = 
ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) 
mContext,pairs);
         mContext.startActivity(sharedIntent,options.toBundle());
     }
 });
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            height = new int[]{0,0,0,
                    70,70,70,70,};
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.length;
}
}
```

Comment: your code looks OK. What is wrong with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033473/recyclerview-with-items-of-different-height-scrollbar

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko height 70 is too small to see while setting programatically

Comment: why then you are setting it to 70?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView item height and width change dynamically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808433/recyclerview-item-height-and-width-change-dynamically-android)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but its large enough to see while we are setting it in XML without setting programatically\

Comment: you mean that you don't see the item in the RecyclerView?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes

Comment: @RahulSurendran have you get any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height in .xml is in dp(70dp), while in coding is in pixel.
So, to get the the size correctly, you need to convert dp to px then apply it programmatically:

Convert dp to px:

```
public int DpToPx(Activity activity, int dp){
    Resources r  = activity.getResources();
    int px    = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return px;

}
```

then apply to your layout param:

```
holder.parentLayout.setLayoutParams(newRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        DPToPx(activity, height[position]));
```

Comment: Let me check it sir

Comment: Sir, how can we use this in adapter, bacause in adapter activty is not accessable

Comment: set it in your adapter constructor:

public ListProfileAdapter(String[] list, Context mContext, Activity activity) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.activity = activity;
}

Comment: Here you gave me the solution. you saved my time. Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 3):

try like this.

```
holder.parentLayout.requestLayout();
            if (position == 0 || position==1 || position==2) {
                holder.parentLayout.getLayoutParams().height = height[position];
            } else {
                holder.parentLayout.getLayoutParams().height = height[position];
            }
```

Comment: we can't compare it with positions, because in the next step while we are clicking an item we need to change every height.

Comment: You have added the same line in if and else. Then what is the use of the If condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can try StaggeredGridLayoutManager for asymmetric items.

try change this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
```

to this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Some of the examples: 
 
[1: Staggered GridView](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/)

[2: StaggeredGridLayout](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Staggered-GridLayout-in-Android)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added views to FlowLayout, but items have all the same height.

solution:
In the item layout xml, use RelativeLayout as root only and ensure the layout whose  child view be dynamically added is surrounded with RelativeLayout too.

just like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  ...
  <FlowLayout />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the Layout size, you need to refresh the UI, try to call this line after the layout size update:

`holder.parentLayout.requestLayout(); //It is necesary to refresh the screen`

Comment: let me look sir.