# How to signal readiness of Recyclers

Tags: android

I have a working app presently, but I don't like the implementation for my `Recyclers`.
My goal is to know when a `Recycler` and `Adapter` is ready to be called without throwing a nullpointer, illegalstate, etc...  This can happen if I try to swap data sets too soon.

My research led me to using the `ViewTreeObserver` draw listeners, but I am hoping that there is a better solution that I missed. Something similar to `MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener` would be nice.

Presently using:

```
    Recycler.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() { 
    @Override public boolean onPreDraw() { 
        // code to signal readiness 
return true; 
        } });
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Share some code of what you are doing at them moment.

Comment: Recycler.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new  ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {  
             @Override
             public boolean onPreDraw() {  
                     // code to signal readiness  
                 return true;  
             }  
         });

Comment: Sorry about the comment formatting.

Comment: Add everything to your question by editing it. Don't post code in comments. :)

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397460/how-to-know-when-the-recyclerview-has-finished-laying-down-the-items

Comment: Android Team, that looks familiar.  Actually, It may have been what led me to using the ViewTreeObserver.