# Scrolling to bottom of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

It seems impossible to scroll to the bottom of a scrollview

I have searched a bunch of other SO posts with no luck.

Some solutions completely disable animations which is not what I want, I want to be able to update some cell sizes with animation, so that solution doesn't work

I don't want the scroll to animation so I can't use smoothScrolling either

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
    result.fold({ conversations ->
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = ConversationsAdapter(conversations)
       
        // Does not work
        binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(conversations.count() - 1)

        // Does not work either
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(conversations.count() - 1)
    },{
        print(it)
    })
})
```

EDIT: Also tried

```
binding.recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(conversations.count() - 1)
}
```

Comment: Try to call recyclerview.scrollToPosition() instead of layoutmanger.scrollToPosition() method. And remove the listener before scrollToPosition()

Comment: Is your `RecyclerView` inside `nestedScrollView`?

Comment: It's not in a nested scrollview

Comment: Move `binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(conversations.count() - 1)` inside `binding.recyclerView.post()`. That should work if i understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wait for RecyclerView [finishes laying down items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492441/11210096)?

Then scroll to bottom inside of `afterMeasured`:

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
    result.fold({ conversations ->
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = ConversationsAdapter(conversations)
       
        recyclerView.afterMeasured {
          binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(conversations.count() - 1)
        }  

    },{
        print(it)
    })
})
```