# LayoutManager not setting stackFromEnd and reverseLayout Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

inside an activity I have an observer I am calling a function to setup adapter. After that I am setting list to my adapter. And doing [How to know when the RecyclerView has finished laying down the items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52492441). And setting layout manager on that. But it's not working.

**activity.kt**

```
class activity : BaseActivity() {

 private var cAdapter: cdAdapter? = null

    fun setupObserver(){
       viewModel.list.observe(this, { value ->
            if (cAdapter == null) {
                setupAdapter()
            }
            submitList(value)
            binding.cRecyclerView.afterMeasured {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context).apply {
                    direction(this)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
   private fun setupAdapter() {
        cAdapter = cdAdapter()
        binding.cRecyclerView.adapter = cAdapter
   }
  
   private fun direction(linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) {
        linearLayoutManager.apply {
           // if (binding.cRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            //    logE("Yes can scroll")
            //} else {
            //    logE("No scroll")
            // }
              
            if (viewModel.itemsAreMorethanTwo()) {
                stackFromEnd = true
                reverseLayout = true
                val index = viewModel.findLastBiggerValue()
                if (index != null && index >= 0) {
                    scrollToPosition(index)
                }
            } else {
                stackFromEnd = false
                reverseLayout = true
            }
        }
    }

     inline fun <T : View> T.afterMeasured(crossinline f: T.() -> Unit) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    f()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Basically inside `direction` function I am checking that if item has more than two value, i'm using **reverse** layout as well as **stackFromEnd** as **true**. As you see inside `direction` function some lines are commented and I need to check that my items are less than the whole height, i.e. I don't want to scroll up or down and the whole items consist in a single screen

1. **For the commented section, I want to know if the view is scrollable or not**.
2. **the code below is working and above code is not**.

If I move this code from observer

```
binding.cRecyclerView.afterMeasured {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context).apply {
         direction(this)
    }
}
```

inside like this

```
private fun setupAdapter() {
         cAdapter = cdAdapter()
            binding.cRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter = cAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context).apply {
                setLayoutDirection(this)
            }
       }
    }
```

When I move this piece of code in **setupAdapter** the commented section does not work though it sets the layout manager correctly.
What I am doing wrong in above code? Please suggest me something.

Comment: Have you got any answers?

Comment: @RonWeasley nope..